# How to count the occurrence of an item from a list within a dictionary (python)

Tags: list, function, dictionary

Below is a dictionary named `daily_purchases` that maps a person's weekly (Monday to Friday) purchases and contains a list of what they bought.

```
{'Monday': {'Edith': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Carrot', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple'], 'Carol': ['Carrot', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Hannah': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Frank': ['Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Alice': ['Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Eggs', 'Eggs', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Ingrid': ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Bob': ['Eggs', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Gertrude': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Dave': ['Apple', 'Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple']}, 'Tuesday': {'Edith': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Carrot', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple'], 'Carol': ['Carrot', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Hannah': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Frank': ['Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Alice': ['Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Eggs', 'Eggs', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Ingrid': ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Bob': ['Eggs', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Gertrude': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Dave': ['Apple', 'Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple']}, 'Wednesday': {'Edith': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Carrot', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple'], 'Carol': ['Carrot', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Hannah': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Frank': ['Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Alice': ['Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Eggs', 'Eggs', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Ingrid': ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Bob': ['Eggs', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Gertrude': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Dave': ['Apple', 'Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple']}, 'Thursday': {'Edith': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Carrot', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple'], 'Carol': ['Carrot', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Hannah': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Frank': ['Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Alice': ['Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Eggs', 'Eggs', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Ingrid': ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Bob': ['Eggs', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Gertrude': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Dave': ['Apple', 'Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple']}, 'Friday': {'Edith': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Carrot', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple'], 'Carol': ['Carrot', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Hannah': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Frank': ['Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Alice': ['Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Eggs', 'Eggs', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Ingrid': ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Bob': ['Eggs', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Gertrude': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Dave': ['Apple', 'Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple']}}
```

Ultimately, I want to create a graph of each purchase for the week for each person. For example, Edith bought X (total) apples this week. This is my code so far:

```
                def itemCounter(lst,i):
                        #INPUT: item list and items 
                        #OUTPUT: count times someone bought a particular item  
                        count = 0 
                        for ele in lst: 
                                if (ele ==i):
                                        count = count + 1
                                return count 
                        for day, day_values in daily_purchases.items():
                                for name, items in day_values.items():
                                        for item in items:
                                                item = itemCounter(i) 
                                                items = itemCounter(last)
```

I am not sure which data structure is appropriate to create the graph and why the counter isn't returning the value I want

Answer (score 1):

How is your graph supposed to look like?
Packing your weekly values in a dataframe would allow you to represent in any form:

```py
import pandas as pd

daily_purchases = {'Monday': {'Edith': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Carrot', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple'], 'Carol': ['Carrot', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Hannah': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Frank': ['Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Alice': ['Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Eggs', 'Eggs', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Ingrid': ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Bob': ['Eggs', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Gertrude': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Dave': ['Apple', 'Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple']}, 'Tuesday': {'Edith': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Carrot', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple'], 'Carol': ['Carrot', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Hannah': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Frank': ['Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Alice': ['Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Eggs', 'Eggs', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Ingrid': ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Bob': ['Eggs', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Gertrude': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Dave': ['Apple', 'Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple']}, 'Wednesday': {'Edith': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Carrot', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple'], 'Carol': ['Carrot', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Hannah': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Frank': ['Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Alice': ['Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Eggs', 'Eggs', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Ingrid': ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Bob': ['Eggs', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Gertrude': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Dave': ['Apple', 'Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple']}, 'Thursday': {'Edith': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Carrot', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple'], 'Carol': ['Carrot', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Hannah': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Frank': ['Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Alice': ['Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Eggs', 'Eggs', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Ingrid': ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Bob': ['Eggs', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Gertrude': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Dave': ['Apple', 'Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple']}, 'Friday': {'Edith': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Carrot', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple'], 'Carol': ['Carrot', 'Banana', 'Banana', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Hannah': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Frank': ['Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Alice': ['Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Eggs', 'Eggs', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Ingrid': ['Banana', 'Banana', 'Ice Pops'], 'Bob': ['Eggs', 'Banana', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Dragon Fruit', 'Carrot', 'Dragon Fruit'], 'Gertrude': ['Hamburger Buns', 'Banana', 'Eggs', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Eggs', 'Apple', 'Carrot', 'Eggs', 'Banana'], 'Dave': ['Apple', 'Ice Pops', 'Carrot', 'Carrot', 'Ice Pops', 'Hamburger Buns', 'Apple']}}

def get_weekly_purchases(day_pur):
    output_dict = {}
    for _, day_val in day_pur.items():
        for pers, lst in day_val.items():
            output_dict[pers] = output_dict.setdefault(pers, {})
            for elt in lst:
                output_dict[pers][elt] = output_dict[pers].get(elt, 0) + 1

    return pd.DataFrame(output_dict).fillna(0)

print(get_weekly_purchases(daily_purchases))
```

Output:

```
                Edith  Carol  Hannah  Frank  Alice  Ingrid   Bob  Gertrude  Dave
Apple            10.0   10.0    10.0    5.0    0.0     0.0   0.0       5.0  10.0
Banana            5.0   15.0     5.0    0.0    0.0    10.0   5.0      10.0   0.0
Hamburger Buns   10.0    0.0    10.0    0.0    5.0     0.0   5.0      10.0   5.0
Carrot            5.0   15.0     0.0   10.0    0.0     0.0   5.0       5.0  10.0
Dragon Fruit      0.0    5.0     5.0    5.0   10.0     0.0  10.0       0.0   0.0
Eggs              0.0    5.0     5.0    0.0   15.0     0.0   5.0      15.0   0.0
Ice Pops          0.0    0.0     5.0    5.0    5.0     5.0   0.0       5.0  10.0
```

Edit: it's not quite clear how you want to represent items (separate bars / stacked). Here is an example for stacked bar (better readable in my opinion):

```
df = get_weekly_purchases(daily_purchases)
df.T.plot(kind='bar', title="Purchases in a week", stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

It gives you:
[image]

Comment: A bar graph with x axis having the names and y axis being number of times purchased. Would I do something like this?                 df.plot(x= "names", y= "items", kind="bar") 
                plt.title("Purchases in a week") 
                plt.ylabel("Number bought")